# How to modify the iterator when hashset values are added

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

I have written code for to find out the broken links present in the website using selenium webdriver in java. As links are getting added in the `HashSet` while launching the different urls. I have tried to read the added urls from `HashSet` it stops executing after sometime. This is happening because iterator remains as it is even adding of new links to the `HashSet`. I want that execution should continue for all links present in the `HashSet`.
[I have tried to convert `Set` to an array but duplicate links are executing multiple times.]

```
public Set<String> unique_links;
HashMap<String, String> result;
Set<String> finalLinkSet = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> uniqueLinkSet = new HashSet<>();
// String[] finalLinkArray;
String[] finalLinkArray;
boolean isValid = false;
FileWriter fstream;
BufferedWriter out;
int count = 1;
int FC = 0;
Set<String> secondaryset = new HashSet<>();

// String Responsecode = null;

@Test
public void LinkTesting() throws IOException, RowsExceededException,
        WriteException {

    w.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    unique_links = new HashSet<String>();
    w.get("http://www.skyscape.com");

    ArrayList<WebElement> urlList = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    urlList = (ArrayList<WebElement>) w.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    setFinalLinkSet(getUniqueList(urlList));


    for(Iterator<String> i = finalLinkSet.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {

    System.out.println(finalLinkSet.size());
    String currenturl = (String) i.next();


     if ((currenturl.length() > 0 && currenturl
     .startsWith("http://www.skyscape.com"))) {

     if (!currenturl.startsWith("http://www.skyscape.com/estore/")&&
     (!currenturl.startsWith("http://www.skyscape.com/demos/"))) {
     System.out.println(currenturl);

     getResponseCode(currenturl);
     }
     }
     }


    writetoexcel();
}

public void setFinalLinkSet(Set<String> finalLinkSet) {
    this.finalLinkSet = finalLinkSet;
}

// function to get link from page and return array list of links
public Set<String> getLinksOnPage(String url) {

    ArrayList<WebElement> secondaryUrl = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    secondaryUrl = (ArrayList<WebElement>) w.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for (int i = 0; i < secondaryUrl.size(); i++) {

        secondaryset.add((secondaryUrl.get(i).getAttribute("href")
                .toString()));
    }

    return secondaryset;
}

// function to fetch link from array list and store unique links in hashset
public Set<String> getUniqueList(ArrayList<WebElement> url_list) {

    for (int i = 0; i < url_list.size(); i++) {
        uniqueLinkSet.add(url_list.get(i).getAttribute("href").toString());
    }

    return uniqueLinkSet;
}

public boolean getResponseCode(String url) {
    boolean isValid = false;

    if (result == null) {
        result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        w.navigate().to(url);
        HttpURLConnection h = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        h.setRequestMethod("GET");
        h.connect();
        System.out.println(h.getResponseCode());

        if ((h.getResponseCode() != 500) && (h.getResponseCode() != 404)
                && (h.getResponseCode() != 403)
                && (h.getResponseCode() != 402)
                && (h.getResponseCode() != 400)
                && (h.getResponseCode() != 401)) {
            // && (h.getResponseCode() != 302)) {

            //getLinksOnPage(url);

            Set<String> unique2 = getLinksOnPage(url);
            setFinalLinkSet(unique2);

            result.put(url.toString(), "" + h.getResponseCode());

        } else {

            result.put(url.toString(), "" + h.getResponseCode());

            FC++;
        }

        return isValid;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return isValid;
}

private void writetoexcel() throws IOException, RowsExceededException,
        WriteException {

    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("OldLinks.xls");
    WritableWorkbook wwb = Workbook.createWorkbook(fo);
    WritableSheet ws = wwb.createSheet("Links", 0);
    int recordsToPrint = result.size();

    Label HeaderUrl = new Label(0, 0, "Urls");
    ws.addCell(HeaderUrl);
    Label HeaderCode = new Label(1, 0, "Response Code");
    ws.addCell(HeaderCode);
    Label HeaderStatus = new Label(2, 0, "Status");
    ws.addCell(HeaderStatus);
    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = result.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext() && count < recordsToPrint) {
        String Responsecode = null;
        Map.Entry<String, String> pairs = it.next();
        System.out.println("Value is --" + pairs.getKey() + "  -  "
                + pairs.getValue() + "\n");

        Label Urllink = new Label(0, count, pairs.getKey());

        Label RespCode = new Label(1, count, pairs.getValue());

        Responsecode = pairs.getValue();
        System.out.println(Responsecode);
        if ((Responsecode.equals("500")) || (Responsecode.equals("404"))
                || (Responsecode.equals("403"))
                || (Responsecode.equals("400"))
                || (Responsecode.equals("402"))
                || (Responsecode.equals("401"))) {
            // || (Responsecode.equals("302"))) {
            Label Status1 = new Label(2, count, "Fail");
            ws.addCell(Status1);
        } else {
            Label Status2 = new Label(2, count, "Pass");
            ws.addCell(Status2);
        }

        try {
            ws.addCell(Urllink);
        } catch (RowsExceededException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (WriteException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ws.addCell(RespCode);
        count++;
    }

    Label FCS = new Label(4, 1, "Fail Urls Count is = " + FC);
    ws.addCell(FCS);
    wwb.write();
    wwb.close();

}
```

}

Comment: There is too much code, and (IMO) most of it is irrelevant to your question.  Please reduce this to a SMALL but complete working example that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In short, as far as I understand the problem: You have (at least) two threads (although I couldn't find them in the too long code example), one is adding entries to the HashSet, and the other should continuously list elements as they are added to the HashSet.
1st: You should use a concurrent data structure for this, but not a simple HashSet.
2nd: Iterators of HashSet do not support concurrent modification, so you can now have an iterator "waiting" for new entries being added.

Best is to change your code to use some kind of event-message pattern (sometimes also called broadcaster/listener), where the finding of a new URL generates an event, that other parts of your code listen to and then write them to the file.

Comment: No he does not have 2 Threads. He is just replacing (althoung intending to update) the list over which he is iterating from within a method that is called from inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop finishes (earlier than desired) for the following reasons:

- The initiation part `Iterator<String> i = finalLinkSet.iterator()`of your for-loop

  ```
  for(Iterator<String> i = finalLinkSet.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
  ```

  is evaluated *once* when the loop is started. Hence it will not react on changes to `finalLinkSet` even if there where some.
- You are not making any changes to `finalLinkSet`. Instead you are overwriting it with a new set when calling

  ```
  setFinalLinkSet(unique2);
  ```

So instead you should:

- Use a list, so you have ordered elements. (Adding entries to an unordered set will make it impossible to know which ones you already have iterated over). I suggest you therefore use an `ArrayList<String>`, so you have constant access time by the little drawback of performance for resizing on adding new entries.
- Modify your for-loop to use an index, so evaluating the init-part once is sufficient and you can react on the changing size of list:

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < finalLinkList.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(finalLinkSet.size());
      String currenturl = (String) finalLinkList.get(i);
  ```
- Then instead of overwriting the list you should:

  ```
  // for both occurrences
  addToFinalLinkList(...); // see new code below
  ```

  and

  ```
  public void addToFinalLinkList(Set<String> tempSet) {
      for(String url: tempSet)
      {
          if(!finalLinkList.contains(url))
              finalListList.add(url);  
      }
  }
  ```

  I know this is not best from the performance point of view, but since you are inside a test, this shouldn't be a problem from what I see...